# Change linear layout to constraint layout by hitting a button

Tags: java, android, android-studio

So the screen is going to have some textViews and a button, by hitting the button, the layout should change from linear to constraint, vice versa.
these two should have exact same paddings and alignments. I have my linear layout set up, how do I make an extra screen to perform constraint layout?

do I simply hide and unhide components?
or is there a way to overlap the components?
maybe create another layout.xml something like that?

Comment: If you're changing your root from one view group to another, but keeping the same alignment etc, what's the point? What are you actually looking at changing?

Comment: @HenryTwist Im a newbie to android studio, just testing if I could do that. I shouldnt see anything change actually!

Comment: Try creating two different layouts and inflate accordingly.

Comment: why do you want to change our parent type from linear to constraint?

Answer (score -1):

You can make an copy of your linear layout.

Then open the copied new layout in design view, right click the root LinearLayout object in the hierarchy view, select "Convert LinearLayout to ConstraintLayout" from the popup menu.

I don't think it can create 100% same layout, but good luck!